# Spark graphx issue

Tags: apache-spark, graphframes

I am trying to follow the example in 
https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/graph-analysis/graphframes/user-guide-python.html

However when changing some criteria the result is not as per expectation.
Please see the steps below -

from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit, when
from graphframes import *

```
vertices = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
  ("a", "Alice", 34),
  ("b", "Bob", 36),
  ("c", "Charlie", 30),
  ("d", "David", 29),
  ("e", "Esther", 32),
  ("f", "Fanny", 36),
  ("g", "Gabby", 60)], ["id", "name", "age"])

edges = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
  ("a", "b", "follow"),
  ("b", "c", "follow"),
  ("c", "b", "follow"),
  ("f", "c", "follow"),
  ("e", "f", "follow"),
  ("e", "d", "follow"),
  ("d", "a", "follow"),
  ("a", "e", "follow")
], ["src", "dst", "relationship"])

g = GraphFrame(vertices, edges)
```

Now one change I have done in "relationship" column , all values are "follow" instead of friend.

Now below query is running fine -

```
g.bfs(fromExpr ="name = 'Alice'",toExpr = "age < 32", edgeFilter ="relationship != 'friend'" , maxPathLength = 10).show()

+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+----------------+
|          from|            e0|             v1|            e1|              to|
+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+----------------+
|[a, Alice, 34]|[a, e, follow]|[e, Esther, 32]|[e, d, follow]|  [d, David, 29]|
|[a, Alice, 34]|[a, b, follow]|   [b, Bob, 36]|[b, c, follow]|[c, Charlie, 30]|
+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+----------------+
```

but if I change the filter criteria from 32 to 40 , wrong result is being fetched -

```
>>> g.bfs(fromExpr ="name = 'Alice'",toExpr = "age < 35", edgeFilter ="relationship != 'friend'" , maxPathLength = 10).show()
+--------------+--------------+
|          from|            to|
+--------------+--------------+
|[a, Alice, 34]|[a, Alice, 34]|
+--------------+--------------+
```

Ideally it should fetch similar result from first query because filter condition is still getting satisfied for all rows.

Any explanation behind this ?

Answer (score 0):

bfs() search for the first result that meet your predicate. Alice age is 34, it meets  `toExpr = "age < 35"` predicate so you got zero length path starting from Alice. Please change toExpr for something more specific. for example `toExpr ="name = 'David' or name = 'Charlie'"` Should give you exactly the same result as in the first query.

Comment: Thanks You @Artem for explaining